# Динамические аргументы для file_get_html

Tags: php, html

Я из *.txt читаю строки в массив посредством `file()`:

```
$arr=file('file.txt');
```

Далее я хочу получить `file_get_html($arr[0]); //0` - пример. Делаю это в цикле с последующей обработкой страницы (поэтому и "динамические аргументы").

Но проблема в том, что `file_get_html();` не хочет кушать такого вида аргументы.
И такое тоже не помогло:

```
$url=$arr[0];
file_get_html($url);
```

Ошибка:

> Warning: file_get_contents()
>   [function.file-get-contents]: Filename
>   cannot be empty in
>   Z:\home\base.ru\www\simplehtmldom_1_5\simple_html_dom.php
>   on line 75

Подскажите, как быть (как заставить-то отобразить страницу)?

**Обновление**

Нет, нет... Со считыванием нет проблем. Правильно массив возвращает массив строк, с которым мы потом работаем, к примеру:

```
$arr=file('file.txt');
file_get_html($arr[0]); //0 - пример

echo $arr[0]; //выдает то, что надо
```

Comment: Также проблема была решена следующим способом:

    $arr=file('file.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция file() вернет массив строк. Вам, наверное, нужен `file_get_contents()`.

**Обновление**

Фильтруйте пустые строки, значит.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: @PostMix, фильтруйте пустые строки значит

Comment: Пустых строк нет.
Проблема решена, посредством считывания из БД.
Там норм работает все. А с файлом не хочет.
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @PostMix, ну как нет, если ошибка именно на этом месте и возникает?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, при вызове `file_get_html ()` идет вызов функции `file_get_contents ()`.

Так вот `file_get_contents()` будет работать только в том случае, если на том хостинге, куда вы пытаетесь постучать, ЭТО РАЗРЕШЕНО!

Так что мой вам совет: юзайте cURL - и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. Позже попробую и таким способом.